# ibm mq test return MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'

Tags: java, testing, ibm-mq

I have web app that allow sent messages to queue, it deployed on Websphere Application Server and work very well. 
I try to build light environment for autotests, but when i try to sent message to queue from test it returns to me `MQJE001: Completion Code '2', Reason '2035'`

I thought that problem in CHLAUTH rules but seems that i have all rights.

```
C:/> dspmqaut -m M00.EDOGO -n OEP.FROM.GW_SBAST.DLV -t q -p out-bychek-ao
        Entity out-bychek-ao has the following authorizations for object OEP.FROM.GW_SBA
        ST.DLV:
        get
        browse
        put
        inq
        set
        crt
        dlt
        chg
        dsp
        passid
        passall
        setid
        setall
        clr
```

**error from logs :**

```
AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity 'out-bychek-a' cannot
be obtained.
EXPLANATION:
The Object Authority Manager was unable to obtain a SID for the specified
entity. This could be because the local machine is not in the domain to locate
the entity, or because the entity does not exist.
ACTION:
Ensure that the entity is valid, and that all necessary domain controllers are
available. This might mean creating the entity on the local machine.
----- amqzfubn.c : 2252 -------------------------------------------------------
    7/9/2018 15:39:57 - Process(2028.3) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                      Host(SBT-ORSEDG-204) Installation(Installation1)
                      VRMF(7.5.0.4) QMgr(M00.EDOGO)

 AMQ9557: Queue Manager User ID initialization failed.

   EXPLANATION:
   The call to initialize the User ID failed with CompCode 2 and Reason 2035.
    ACTION:
Correct the error and try again.
----- cmqxrsrv.c : 1975 -------------------------------------------------------

 7/9/2018 15:39:57 - Process(2028.3) User(MUSR_MQADMIN) Program(amqrmppa.exe)
                  Host(SBT-ORSEDG-204) Installation(Installation1)
                  VRMF(7.5.0.4) QMgr(M00.EDOGO)

AMQ9999: Channel 'SC.EDOGO' to host '10.82.38.188' ended abnormally.
EXPLANATION:
The channel program running under process ID 2028(11564) for channel 'SC.EDOGO'
ended abnormally. The host name is '10.82.38.188'; in some cases the host name
cannot be determined and so is shown as '????'.
ACTION:
Look at previous error messages for the channel program in the error logs to
determine the cause of the failure. Note that this message can be excluded
completely or suppressed by tuning the "ExcludeMessage" or "SuppressMessage"
 attributes under the "QMErrorLog" stanza in qm.ini. Further information can be
 found in the System Administration Guide.
----- amqrmrsa.c : 909 --------------------------------------------------------
```

notice `AMQ8075: Authorization failed because the SID for entity '`**out-bychek-a**`' cannot` in my account name lost last letter. Is it normal?

and this

```
 DISPLAY CHLAUTH('SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN') MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS('127.0.0.1') CLNTUSER('out-bychek-ao')

 7 : DISPLAY CHLAUTH('SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN') MATCH(RUNCHECK) ALL ADDRESS('127.0.0.1') CLNTUSER('out-bychek-ao')

AMQ8898: Display channel authentication record details - currently disabled.

   CHLAUTH(SYSTEM.*)                       TYPE(ADDRESSMAP)

   DESCR(Default rule to disable all SYSTEM channels)

   CUSTOM( )                               ADDRESS(*)

   USERSRC(NOACCESS)                       WARN(NO)

   ALTDATE(2016-11-14)                     ALTTIME(17.33.34)
```

```
dmpmqaut -m M00.EDOGO -n OEP.FROM.GW_SBAST.DLV -t q -p out-bychek-ao -e
profile    : OEP.FROM.GW_SBAST.DLV
object type: queue
entity     : out-bychek-ao@alpha
entity tyoe: principal
authority  : allmqi dlt chg dsp clr
- - - - - - - - -
profile    : CLASS
object type: queue
entity     : out-bychek-ao@alpha
entity tyoe: principal
authority  : clt
```

Comment: IBM MQ is limited to 12 character users.

Comment: it mean that i need to change my user name to will my test work?

Comment: Since your username is 13 then yes.  Add the outpur from this command to your question: `dmpmqaut -m M00.EDOGO -n OEP.FROM.GW_SBAST.DLV -t q -p out-bychek-ao -e`

Comment: @JoshMc updated

Comment: Try specifying the @alpha when you connect.

Comment: yes, that's work, thank you!

Comment: I'm post a answer with the details.

Comment: @JoshMc yes, it will great!

Comment: Anton, where are you specifying the username `out-bychek-ao@alpha`?  I know that by adding the @alpha things started to work, but can you clarify if this is being set either Programmatically or via an authentication alias on the WAS server, or does WAS run as the user `out-bychek-ao`, or is the `MCAUSER('out-bychek-ao@alpha')` set on the `SVRCONN` channel `SC.EDOGO`, or are you setting it via `CHLAUTH` rules?

Comment: @JoshMc i add new constructor of class that send to queue with login and password and pass it to it

Comment: Anton, to confirm you do not have `out-bychek-ao@alpha` in your channel `MCAUSER` or any `CHLAUTH` record on the queue manager?  From your comment I take it mean you pass it  with something like `createQueueConnection("user", "password")`, or `cf.createConnection("user", "password")`.